# How to check if node containing certain text exists in XML DOM?

Tags: xml, xpath, vb6

My XML is as below:

[image]

I need to check whether `"anil"` is in the DOM or not without using loop. Is it possible to do this in one line?

This is the code I tried:

```
If not(xmldom.selectsinglenode("//xml/xmlfile/name/"+xname)is nothing) then
    .....
end if
```

Here `xname` will be the text (eg `anil` or `amith`).

Comment: Please show the codes you tried. Btw, still using VB6 ?

Comment: Please **edit**  your question to add codes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XPath to get `<name>` element having inner text equals `anil` is as follow :

```
//xml/xmlfile/name[.='anil']
```

So the string parameter of `selectsinglenode()` should look about like this instead (or better yet using `/` instead of `//` at the beginning) :

```
"//xml/xmlfile/name[.='"+xname+"']"
```

Comment: @JakBalikai side note: you *really* need to learn about [accepting answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271861) as you haven't done it in any of your questions so far, despite an answer was helpful or has solved the problem in question

Comment: You're welcome, and I appreciate that you heed the comment

Comment: and what if, if i want to assign that parent node to another node,

Comment: my honour, sorry to interrupt you again, btw wat if i want to get that parent node to another node.... i tried this                                            set tempnode=xmlDoc.selectsinglenode("//xml/xmlfile/[name='"+xname+"']/name") where am i wrong bro

Comment: it should be something like : `set tempnode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode("//xml/xmlfile[name='"+xname+"']/name")`

Comment: Xpath predicate (`[...]`) is applied to element *directly* to the left of it, so `/[...]` is not a valid XPath expression because there is no element to which the predicate will be applied